# How to get GPG working with Outlook 2013?

Tags: encryption, microsoft-outlook-2013, gnupg, public-key-encryption, smime

My OS is Windows 8.1 Update 1 x64. I have Outlook 2013 and just installed GPG4Win (latest, 2.2.2, full version).

When I now launch Outlook 2013, I still don't see any UI/options to setup certificates and send encrypt an encrypted email (perhaps to myself as a test message). How do I get started?

I must use Outlook, so suggesting another mail client is a non-starter.

Comment: GgpOL only supports 32 bit versions of Outlook. Make sure you're not using a 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at gpg4o ([enter link description here](http://www.gpg4o.com)).
It is not free but it just does the job.
IMHO the best PGP solution for Outlook.

They also offer a trial which persuaded us to 100%.

Comment: This option is closed source.

Comment: So what if it's closed source?

Answer (score 2):

My company, Encryptomatic.com, has released a new open pgp encryption addon for MS Outlook 2016 thru 2007. It supports both 64 and 32 bit versions of Outlook. Installer is signed. Supports key servers, signing, etc.  We think its important that email encryption is accessible and easy, so we made it completely free for personal use. Can't post the link here but you can get it on our website.

Sorry for the plug, but it seemed quite relevant to the subject.

Comment: This option is presently closed source.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook 2010 and 2013 you need to install  Outlook Privacy Plugin with Gpg4win (OpenPGP encryption plugin). I believe that above will fix your issue

Comment: That plugin doesn't install under Windows 8.1

Comment: Also doesn't work with 64 bit versions of Office (probably the default by now). In practical terms, it's obsolete.